# How can I set ACF fields to be displayed according my custom hierarchical order?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a lawyers website using php, wordpress and its ACF plugin. I have a list of lawyers that are generated from my db which were manually entered by the user. Right now they generate randomly when I display them. e.g 
1) Mario - Founder 
2) Peter - Trainee 
3) David - Associate
..and so on.

How can I display those according to my hierarchical order? e.g Founder, Partner, Associate, Trainee ...

Here is what I have in a page with related laywers (office page showing related lawyers):

```
 <li><div class="rlawyers_wrap">
                    <?php
                    $proffessionals = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'proffessionals',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'professional_office_link', // name of custom field
                                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            )
                        )
                    ));?>
                    <?php if( $proffessionals ): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $proffessionals as $proffessional ): ?>
                            <li>
                                <small class="rel_qualification"><?php echo get_field('qualification', $proffessional);?> </small>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    //expose 
                                    var qualifications = '<?php echo get_field('qualification', $proffessional);?>'
                                </script>
                                <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $proffessional->ID ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title( $proffessional->ID ); ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any way to do that with php, or within wordpress? I managed to sort them alphabetically either ascending or descending, but I couldn't figure out how to do the "customizable" sorting. If anyone could help, I would be really grateful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the separate table for Founder, Partner, Associate, Trainee with column rang: 1, 2, 3 .... and make tables relation 1 to many. For "customizable" sorting, you must have "customizable" column in table, and "customizable" new table.

Comment: Problem is that the db is massive. I don't want to manually adjust it. Do you have any solution that php, javascript or any wordpress plugin might solve this problem programmatically?